# Why wont it append to the array in the EM algorithim?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am trying to get this expected max algorithm working although i have issues with the Value of the arrays. Although i thought i could append the values into “W” but, it says that it has no elements.
Therefore the shape of the arrays don’t match. How can i fix this?!?!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# should be a non-singular matrix and a numpy array, only actions for data.
data = [0.42545656, 0.378219348, 0.673857237
        0.47827463, 0.821934844, 0.472892847]


mu, sigma = data.mean(), np.std(data, dtype=np.float32)

for a in range(mat_size):
    noise = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(data))
    data.append(noise)


def expectation_max(data, max_iter=1000):
    data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    mu = data.mean()
    cov = data.cov()

    for x in range(max_iter):
        w = []
        # perform the E part of algorithm
        for i in data:
            wk = (5 + len(data))/(5 + np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(i - mu), np.linalg.inv(cov)), (i - mu)))
            w.append(wk)
            w = np.array(w)

        # perform the M part of the algorithm
        mu = (np.dot(w, data))/(np.sum(w))

        c = 0
        for i in range(len(data)):
            c += w[i] * np.dot((data[i] - mu), (np.transpose(data[i] - mu)))
        cov = c/len(data)


        mu0 = mu
        c0 = cov
    print(np.float32(c0))

    return mu0, c0
```

Comment: The error is the shapes are not equal for the dot product when defining mu the second time.

Comment: `w = np.array(w)` should be outside the for loop, I think?

Comment: I’ll try it, thank you

Comment: Unfortunately it gave me the same error